# Different meanings of "zu"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, german-to-english

I have seen sentences in which `zu` was used for **"closed"** and others in which `geschlossen` was used.

**examples:**

geschlossen:

> `die Tür ist geschlossen`

zu:

> `die Tür ist zu` or `ihre Augen waren zu`

Also `zu` sometimes means `too` or `to` as well. When should I use `zu` as `too` or `to` and where should i use `zu` as `closed`?

I consulted some dictionaries such as [this one](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/german-english/zu) but I didn't understand where to use which one.

Comment: Mantafahrer hält an der Ampel und fragt einen Passanten"Wo geht's'n hier bei Aldi?" - "**Zu** Aldi" - "Watt, schon halb sieben?"

Comment: Welcome to german.SE :)        Questions that can be answered with a dictionary are actually not allowed. Maybe you can explain why a dictionary could not help you.

Comment: Words have different meanings depending on context and usually a single word can be translated many ways according to what is meant by the word in the specific situation. The process is 1) Read the German 2) Figure out the meaning based on context 3) Translate the meaning into English. There is no way to skip 2 and get anything that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why a [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/german-english/zu) could not help you. Maybe you can elaborate on that..
(Vote for "close"?)

---

**"Zu"** is colloquial for "closed". Both can be used.

---

**"Zu"** can be used as adverb, conjunction or preposition.

> das Kind läuft **zu** seiner Mutter

> the child runs **to** its mother

> das ist **zu** viel

> this is **too** much

---

dictionary:
[duden](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/zu)
[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/german-english/zu)

Comment: Both can be used, but `geschlossen` is **not colloquial**.